# call ajax and asp callbacks through proxy

Tags: asp.net, ajax, proxy, telerik, ihttphandler

I have two parts of my ASP site,
and i'm trying to view one site in the other, using proxy.

i'm doing it through `IHttpHandler`.

The site is looking good through the proxy, but i can't call AJAX, either use ASP callbacks (in my case a [`telerik grid`](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/)).

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik controls (Like other MS AJAX based toolsets) utilize WebResources heavily. Make sure your proxy is transparent for them as well (e.g., either does not route them at all, or that they return succesfully, even though I do not know how one app could server another's webresource request).

Consider just framing those pages (e.g., in RadWindows, RadPanes inside a RadSplitter, simple iframes, whatever fits your design).

You can also try using the CDNs Telerik offers in addition to the MS AJAX CDN,so that less webresoures are being used.